# VMA to VECM representation

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, moving-average, vector-error-correction-model

I'm doing research at the moment and for estimation purposes I need to convert a VMA (equation 9.2.2 in the attached picture) to a VECM model (9.2.1) in picture; does anyone know how to make this conversion?

[image]

Comment: Hi: I have no idea but maybe check out Lutkepohl ( Multiple Time Series ) or Reinsel. Reinsel's book is below. It's the only one I know of that covers the VMA in depth. https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Multivariate-Analysis-Springer-Statistics/dp/0387949186/ref=sr_1_3?crid=20JI0VLCCB85V&keywords=reinsel+time+series&qid=1708172005&sprefix=reinsel+time+series%2Caps%2C68&sr=8-3 Note that I have it somewhere and it's a difficult read.

Comment: Hi again, the picture attached abov is from  Lutkepohl ( Mutiple Time Series ), chapter 9.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at the other reference :-)

Comment: Also a (tiny other question): Do you know, if the MA rep. is the same as an 'ordinary' rep? like is the MA the same as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model?

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Comment: Hi: I can't help but it's not the same as the MA you linked to because those things that are multiplying the $u_t$ are matrices. I would google for Beveridge-Nelson MA representation because both Beverridge and Nelson well known for the "Beveridge Nelson Decomposition" so I'm sure you can find something on it. Of course, that doesn't mean it will be necessarily easy to understand.

Comment: Also, check out Chapter 6 or, in the last case, email Dr. Lutkepohl and ask him if he knows where more information can be found. ~15 years ago, I emailed him a few times asking him about VARS and he was quite responsive and helpful. I'm sorry that I can't help.

Comment: Hi again, I have found the solution to the problem by using the textbook from Dr. Lutkepohl.

Comment: Kjetil, I'm not familiar with LaTeX; hence, I'm not going to change it. In case is it against the guidelines of the site, please delete the post.

Comment: Okay. I'm glad you found the solution.

Comment: @user406838, if you have found the solution, consider posting it as an answer, so that other people with the same question would have an answer, too.